# Do classes which have a vector has a member have memory issues

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I am just starting out C++, so sorry if this is a dumb question. I have a class Braid whose members are vectors. I have not written an assignment operator. When I do a lot of assignments to an object of the type Braid, I run into memory issues :-

```
 0  0xb7daff89 in _int_malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0xb7db2583 in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0xb7f8ac59 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0804d05e in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate (this=0xbf800204, __n=1)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/ext/new_allocator.h:89
#4  0x0804cb0e in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate (this=0xbf800204, __n=1)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/bits/stl_vector.h:140
#5  0x0804c086 in _Vector_base (this=0xbf800204, __n=1, __a=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/bits/stl_vector.h:113
#6  0x0804b4b7 in vector (this=0xbf800204, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.4.3/../../../../include/c++/4.4.3/bits/stl_vector.h:242
#7  0x0804b234 in Braid (this=0xbf800204) at braid.h:13
#8  0x080495ed in Braid::cycleBraid (this=0xbf8001b4) at braid.cpp:191
#9  0x080497c6 in Braid::score (this=0xbf800298, b=...) at braid.cpp:251
#10 0x08049c46 in Braid::evaluateMove (this=0xbf800468, move=1, pos=0, depth=2, b=...)
```

I suspect that these memory issues are because the vectors are getting resized. What I want to know is whether objects of type Braid automatically expand when its members expand? the code I am writing is really long so I will post the section which is causing the problems. Here is the relevant section of the code :-

```
class Braid 
{
private :
  vector<int> braid; //Stores the braid.  
  int strands;
  vector < vector<bool> > history; 
  vector < vector<bool> > CM;    
public :
  Braid () : strands(0) {}
  Braid operator * (Braid);
  Braid* inputBraid(int,vector<int>);
  int printBraid();
  int printBraid(vector<vector<int>::iterator>);
  vector<int>::size_type size() const;
               .....
               .....
}
```

Here is the function which causes the issue :-

```
int Braid::evaluateMove(int move,int pos,int depth,Braid b)
{
 int netscore = 0;
 Braid curr(*this);
 curr = curr.move(move,pos);
 netscore += curr.score(b);

 while(depth > 1)
 {
   netscore += curr.evaluateMove(1,0,depth,b);
   netscore += curr.evaluateMove(2,0,depth,b);
   for(int i = 0; i < braid.size();++i)
   {
    netscore += curr.evaluateMove(3,i,depth,b);
    netscore += curr.evaluateMove(4,i,depth,b);
    netscore += curr.evaluateMove(5,i,depth,b);
    curr = curr.cycleBraid();
    netscore += curr.evaluateMove(6,0,depth,b);
   }
   --depth;
 }
 return netscore;
}
```

Comment: `Braid* inputBraid(int,vector<int>);` — probably you want to pass a `const vector<int>&` to avoid copying the whole vector.

Comment: What memory problems? Too high memory usage? From the looks of it you should familiarize yourself with references and the `const` keyword.

Comment: @KennyTM :- Thanks for the tip.
@UncleBeans :- As I said I am a complete newbie. I am sort of stuck in the unenviable situation of having to write C++ code in very little time without having properly learned the langauge. Hence, there are bound to be a lot of newbie mistakes. Anyway I am not running of memory but my program crashes with a segmentation fault. From the gdb backtrace it looked to me like a memory allocation error, but I could be utterly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another problem :

```
while(depth > 1)
{
  netscore += curr.evaluateMove(1,0,depth,b);
  ....
  --depth;
}
```

causes endless recursion when depth >1

Comment: Oh, I am not the only one it bothered then :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Changed it in the relevant places to depth-1. 
Dumb mistake but I think I am learning a lot from the comments.

Answer (score 3):

quick read: `Braid curr(*this);` causes a copy. Can't you use a pointer to the Braid?

Comment: The function cycleBraid modify's the Braid, so I make a temporary copy.

Comment: @Billy: Did it for you.  @user: `curr = curr.move(move,pos);` looks like overkill, blowing away a `Braid` outright.  This code looks like it needs some references and pointers and refactoring, but I can't tell what `Braid` is trying to achieve.  Is it some kind of arcane game theory stuff?

Comment: @Mike I am trying to implement the Braid group 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braid_group

Answer (score 3):

Am I the only remarking a Stack Overflow there ?

I colored out the useless bits (for the purpose of the demo)

```
int Braid::evaluateMove(int move,int pos,int depth,Braid b)
{
  #int netscore = 0;
  #Braid curr(*this);
  #curr = curr.move(move,pos);
  #netscore += curr.score(b);

  while(depth > 1)
  {
    netscore += curr.evaluateMove(1,0,depth,b);
    #netscore += curr.evaluateMove(2,0,depth,b);
    #for(int i = 0; i < braid.size();++i)
    #{
    #  netscore += curr.evaluateMove(3,i,depth,b);
    #  netscore += curr.evaluateMove(4,i,depth,b);
    #  netscore += curr.evaluateMove(5,i,depth,b);
    #  curr = curr.cycleBraid();
    #  netscore += curr.evaluateMove(6,0,depth,b);
    #}
    --depth;
  }
  return netscore;
}
```

Now if `depth` is superior to `1`... oups

Let's say I do:

- `Braid b; b.evaluateMove(1,0,2,b);`
- it invokes `curr.evaluateMove(1,0,2,b);`
- which invokes `curr.evaluateMove(1,0,2,b);`
- which ...

Well, the system might run out of memory.

*Note: why does `evaluateMove` both copy `this` and ask for a copy of `Braid` (parameter `b`) ? I'd check my `score` method if I was you.*

Answer (score 1):

On an unrelated point, you probably do not want:

```
 vector<bool>
```

as `vector<bool>` is a template specialisation which you should only use if you really, really know what you are doing. Consider `vector <char>` or `deque<bool>` instead.

Comment: I think you meant "consider `vector<char>/vector<int>` or something and `deque<bool>` above... Do I have that right?

Comment: @Billy, no, I meant what I said. `deque<bool>` is not a specialisation and has almost all the features that `vector<bool>` should have had.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Sorry -- I saw a pre-edit version where it just said "consider vector or deque" without specifying the template argument. And no, I did not downvote.

Comment: Sorry, when I down voted it said "as vector is a template specialisation....Consider vector or deque instead"

My bad.

Comment: I'm inclined to disagree with the "do not want". Considering the fact that you've got 2 vectors of vectors of bools, the benefit of `vector<bool>` may outweigh its unusual non-generic nature